# What does the `-o` flag do in `ssh-keygen`?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, ssh-keygen

In gitlab's documentation on [how to generate ssh key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/index.html#upgrade-your-rsa-key-pair-to-a-more-secure-format): they suggest to use the `-o` argument. However, this argument does not seem to appear in the [manual of ssh-keygen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen). No error is thrown so it is acceptable. I am wondering what does it do?

Comment: That manpage is far too old, try `https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html`. If you are using *nix, then your own manpages should have told you.

Comment: @Bib for some reason on my system there was no manpages even though it's linux...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ssh-keygen "-o" option [currently does nothing](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/08f579231cd38a1c657aaa6ddeb8ab57a1fd4f5c/ssh-keygen.c#L3454). It's accepted by ssh-keygen for compatibility, but ignored.

It used to [cause ssh-keygen to save the key in a different key format](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/ed7bd5d93fe14c7bd90febd29b858ea985d14d45), but that key format is now the default behavior.

It looks like this change was made for OpenSSH 7.8 in 2018. It's not unreasonable in 2021 for someone to be following github's instructions using an older version of ssh-keygen in which the option does something useful.